# Retry mocha failed test

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I was trying to implement code to retry the failed test using "mocha-retry"
Below is the sample .

```
describe(retries,' retries-',function () {
var self = this;
    beforeAll(function () {
        global.requireLogin();
    });

this.retries(3);
})
```

I am getting error as 
 Error: ReferenceError: retries is not defined

MAy I know where is the wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describe only accepts two parameters, one being a `String` *describing* the tests scenario and another being a `function` which may contain either more describes or test cases.

Comment: Thanks diegoagullar !! Yeah I tried with                             
            describe(,' retries-',function () {
var self = this;
    beforeAll(function () {
        global.requireLogin();
    });

this.retries(3);
}) however I wann to implement in protractor still I am faing the issue